# Ошибка записи данных в дерево (С++)

Tags: c++, дерево

Добрый день!

При записи данных происходит ошибка. Получается, что не создается узел дерева. Но понять где именно ошибка не могу, и как её исправить, главное. Дерево состоит из рекурсий класса. Создавать отдельно Node проблемно, т.к. в программе другие функции сложно адаптировать. Укажите, пожалуйста, в каком месте ошибка и как её исправить.

Задание: из строки выделяются данные и записываются в узлы дерева в соответствующем формате.

Вот код:

```
class Tree
    {
    public:
        int data;

        Tree *son;
        Tree *brother;

        Tree();
        ~Tree();

        void des(Tree *tree, std::string S);
    };

    Tree::Tree()
    { 
        Tree::data = NULL;

        Tree::son = NULL; 
        Tree::brother = NULL; 
    }

    Tree::~Tree()
    {
        if (son) delete son;
        if (brother) delete brother;
    }

    void Tree::des(Tree *tree, std::string S)
    {
    int dataInt;
string son;
string brother;

//В данной части кода происходит обработка строки S, с вычленением из неё dataInt, строк S и строк brother. В них ошибки нет. Данные правильно преобразуются в переменную int и выводятся на печать. 

        tree->data = dataInt; //Ошибка возникает тут. Пишет что дерево nullptr.  
        std::cout << data << std::endl;
        des(tree->son, son);
        des(tree->brother, brother);
    }

    int main()
    {
        Tree *tree = new Tree(); 
        std::string S = "(1,65,10)";
        tree->des(tree, S);
        tree->print_Tree(tree);
        system("pause");
        delete tree;
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `data` имеет тип `int`. Почему тогда `Tree::data = NULL;`? Что такое `dataInt`? Откуда оно взялось? Что это за чушь: `son != "NULL"`?

Comment: Что это за белиберда `des(tree->son, son)`, если второй параметр `des` имеет тип `std::string`? В общем вы нас обманываете. Ваш код - выдумка, не имеющая ничего общего с реальным кодом. Не надо постить выдуманный код. Приводите реальный код.

Comment: Код реальный. Просто из него убрала то, что к ошибке не относиться. Естественно (в комментарии написано же) что в des идёт обработка строки, вычленение из строки чисел и запись их в dataInt. Переменная son и brother тоже string. И они выходят из оставшейся строки.

Comment: В Tree::data = NULL происходит обычное зануление данных. Чтобы в случае чего не вылезла ерунда какая-нибудь. Можно вместо NULL поставить 0. Разницы не будет. Даже если убрать эту строчку всё равно в месте ошибки писаться данные в неё не будут. В данном случае ошибка в том, что не создается узел дерева. Т.е. ему просто некуда записывать новые данные. Я прошу помощь разобраться именно в этом. Мб в конструкторе что-то не то. Или нужно где то ещё создать новое дерево?

Comment: Исправила код, чтобы был понятнее.

Comment: Не можно, а нужно. Макро-константа NULL предназначена для использования с указателями, а не с целыми значениями. С целыми значениями с некоторых пор она использоваться не может. Поэтому не "можно 0", а именно 0. В остальном: у вас каша из переменных с одинаковыми именами, но разными типами и разными областями видимости. Зачем понадобилась такая невообразимая мешанина?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну так ошибка очевидна. Вызов `tree->des(tree, S);` из `main` сразу приводит к вызовам

```
des(tree->son, son);
des(tree->brother, brother);
```

в то время как `tree->son` и `tree->brother` равны null-указателям. В результате все падает из-за того, что параметр `tree` в этих вызовах будет null-указателем. Все как вы и описали. В чем затруднение-то?

**P.S.** Однако непонятно, зачем вы вообще сделали `des` методом класса `Tree` если к переменным объекта `Tree` через `this` вы в этом методе вообще нигде не обращаетесь, а везде работаете через параметр `tree`.

Comment: Спасибо! Создала новые деревья всё заработало как надо.

Comment: А вот через this почему-то не работает.